# Connect to Oracle database through SSH tunnel in DBeaver

Tags: oracle, ssh, dbeaver

I have access to a VM that runs scripts in batch files to first create SSH tunnel to a remote server, and then execute a number of SQL queries agains an oracle database

I'm trying to gain access to the same database through DBeaver and are having some trouble converting the shell SSH script into the GUI of DBeaver.

The script creates the tunnes like this:

```
@ssh -L 55444:{remoteHostName}:1521 -f -C -N -i {keyFile} {userName}@{hostName} -p 2006
```

Now I have the keyfile and can gain access through putty by entering the data like this:

[image: Putty]

[image: puttyKeyfile]

[image: puttysshtunnel]

This allows me to open up a tunnel and login.

Trying to replicate the same setup in DBeaver looks like this:

[image: DBeavermain]

[image: DBeaver SSH]

testing the tunnel seems to work

[image: testtunnel]

but testing the connection does not

[image]

My guess is that I am doing something wrong when i am setting up the local/remote ports in SSH settings

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Argh only issue was me not changing Service name to SID

Connected now :)